# mysql/php insert/update on duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product info table with more than 130 columns/fields.

I want to write a php script that adds a new product to the table OR updates the existing product if it already exist. The first field is the product key.

The product information is stored in a numbered php array : $product_info[0] to $product_info[130].

Basically something like this :

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES ($product_info[0],$product_info[1],$product_info[2])
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a='$product_info[0]', b='$product_info[1]', c='$product_info[2]'
```

Is there something more efficient than typing each of the 130 fields twice?

Comment: Why on earth would you have 130 columns in a table? Or is your terminology wrong in that you want to insert 130 rows / items?

Comment: As @premiso implies, this probably isn't ideal from a schema perspective. What does this data represent?

Comment: No its over 130 columns of product details... Not my choice.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is, use the [`VALUES()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) function:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES (b), c = VALUES(c)
```

Basically, in the `UPDATE` part, `VALUES(column)` will return the specified value for that column for the current row in question.  So you can do interesting things like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    a = VALUES(a), 
    b = VALUES(b) + VALUES(c),
```

The beauty of that syntax, is it also supports multiple insert rows:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (a, b, c) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?), 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?), 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES (b), c = VALUES(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I would still have to type all 130 fields twice. This is basically the solution I posted in my question with a little twist. I'm looking for something more efficient if it's doable.

Comment: Typo: `KYE` should be `KEY`. This is a single-letter change, so I can't do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MySQL does not support merging... having an ORM can help ease the pain of coding multiple IF EXISTS UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT code

Answer (score 0):

[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: No.  Don't use `REPLACE` if you care about referential integrity.  It deletes if exists, then inserts.  So it'll destroy any foreign key relations.

Comment: Right now the php code checks if the row exists. If it does not exist, it does an INSERT. If it does exist, it does a DELETE query followed by an INSERT query.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @dgw. I never do link-only answers these days. I know better now. Question: Is this answer worth salvaging, or should it just be deleted? I'm busy for the next couple of days, and then on holiday till the end of the month, so *I'm* not going to fix it any time soon.